# Polynomial approximation of $\cot(\pi z)$ on an interval.

Tags: approximation, interpolation

Is there a way to find an accurate polynomial interpolation and approximation of $\cot(\pi z)$ on the interval $0.1 < z < 0.999$ with a polynomial of degree $2$?

The function is clearly continuous at that interval.

I need to use this function to calculate several values of $z$ at that interval and will want to avoid the $1/z$ term in the series expansion of $\cot(\pi z)$ on that interval.

I already have a Fourier series expansion that converges on that interval but it requires $100$ coefficient terms and so I was wondering if there was a way to utilize a simple polynomial to approximate it to a marginal error.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You want to approximate $\cot x$ with $a x^2+b x+c$?

Comment: @SuzuHirose At that interval it's not possible?, I thought as much.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to approximate it accurately or not.

Comment: Do you insist on a polynomial, or would you perhaps prefer a *rational* approximation? After all, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cot(\pi x)}{1/(\pi x)}=1$ so you may want to find an approximation of the form $\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{\pi x}$ where $ax^2+bx+c$ is a good approximation of $\pi x \cot(\pi x)$ - the latter being a much tamer function (having limit is $1$) near zero.

Comment: @StinkingBishop yeah that would have been an easier approximation but I'm actually trying to avoid rational approximations which is also why I avoided the series expansion of cot(pi z)

Comment: You could use the Taylor series around $1/2$ up to the quadratic term. This is **the best** possible approximation of the function with a quadratic polynomial around that point. Still won't be a good approximation on the whole interval because of the nature of the function.

Comment: @jjagmath thanks that works it clearly converges like the Fourier series but it does so with a smaller number of terms unlike the Fourier series, the 10th expansion term is already yielding promising values and I could parametize that to get even better values.

Answer (score 1):

I think that with a polynomial of degree $n \geq 3$ for $0.1 \leq z \leq 0.9$, we could do a "decent" job.

The idea is to minimize
$$\Phi_n=\int_a^{1-a} \Bigg[\cot(\pi z)-\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\,z^k \Bigg]^2\, dz$$ which can be computed explicitly in terms of polylogarithms with complex arguments.

For example, making the numbers rational for $a=0.1$ and $n=3$, the approximation is
$$\frac{73056}{15485}-\frac{219043 }{9272}z+\frac{222361 }{5224}z^2-\frac{222361
   }{7836}z^3$$ giving $\Phi_3=0.00413$.